# How do you apply exponential operations to computed columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like to define a computed column on my SQLAlchemy model class. However it seems like the Column classes are overloaded for some operators like addition but not others like exponents. Below is a very crude example of what I mean.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

Base = declarative_base()

class MyModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = "my_model"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    addition = column_property(id + 2)  # Totally fine
    exponent = column_property(id ** 2)  # TypeError
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Column' and 'int'

I'm rather new to SQLAlchemy so I could be misguided. It seems like a very straightforward use-case but I haven't found much about how to accomplish it thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set constraints based on other columns' values, you could use ORM events. Events are executed at a specific time and allow to run a function on columns of a databse row and possibly change attribute's value.

You could use the `before_commit` event which is sent every time you try to commit the object in the database.

```py
# Import event from SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event

# Your code
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

Base = declarative_base()

class MyModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = "my_model"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    addition = Column(Integer)    # Set your fields as normal Integer without constraints
    exponent = Column(Integer)    # Set your fields as normal Integer without constraints


# Create an event to be executed before commit
@event.listens_for(Table, 'before_commit')
def make_constraints(mapper, connect, target):
    # target is an instance of MyModel
    target.addition = target.id + 1
    target.exponent = target.id ** 2
```

Check out the documentation of ORM events : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html

If you really need some database-level constraint, you could set a `CheckConstraint` on your table.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea but I think for my use-case, it would be preferable that the field is truly computed rather than actually stored in the database. I'd like to tweak the computation easily without needing to migrate existing rows to reflect that tweak. I'm aware of hybrid properties + expression but not so keen on the idea of having to define the computation as both a Python AND an SQL expression. I would rather just have the expression which is why I was trying to use column_property.

Comment: You mean the result does not have to be stored in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`expression.func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) to define the computed column correctly:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_model"
    # ...
    exponent = column_property(func.pow(id, 2))
```